# graalvm 21 new Robot().createScreenCapture(size) returns magnified

Tags: java, swing, exe, screenshot, graalvm-native-image

For the java [project](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.tst.input) below that screencaptures to a jpg file, why

- jar version creates proper jpg file,
- graalvm exe version creates magnified jpg file
- even though they both detects screen size correctly
- Is there any temporary fix?

```
public static void main(String... s) {
    var size = size();
    log.ci("main", "size", size);
    var img = shotPicture(size);
    if (img == null) {
        return;
    }
    var jpg = Path.of("D:\\git\\tst\\com.tugalsan.tst.input\\out.jpg");
    toJpg(img, jpg);
}

static void toJpg(BufferedImage input, Path output) {
    try {
        ImageIO.write(input, "jpg", output.toFile());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static Rectangle size() {
    var localGrapicsEnv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    var screensDevices = localGrapicsEnv.getScreenDevices();
    var allScreenBounds = new java.awt.Rectangle();
    for (var screen : screensDevices) {
        var screenBounds = screen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        allScreenBounds.width += screenBounds.width;
        allScreenBounds.height = Math.max(allScreenBounds.height, screenBounds.height);
    }
    return allScreenBounds;
}

static BufferedImage shotPicture(Rectangle size) {
    try {
        return new Robot().createScreenCapture(size);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

static class log {

    public static void ci(String funcName, Object... oAll) {
        out.print(funcName);
        Arrays.stream(oAll).forEachOrdered(oi -> {
            out.print(" ");
            out.print(oi);
        });
        out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured, it is related to Windows-Settings-System-Display-Scale being %150. Now have to figure out, how to make java detect scale percent?

Comment: I figured that, graalvm native exe cannot detect scaling factor. using this java function->  static float scaleFactor() {return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution() / 96f;}